# How to detect/prevent wifi timeouts on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, timeout, ping

I dont think this is possible, but can client connected to a wifi hotspot detect or even prevent a disconnect due to a timeout?

My guess is that this is not possible as i would imagine this timeout would be a router thing rather than a client thing.

And if a client makes an intervaled ping (e.g. ip address), would this prevent the client from being timed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that WiFi timeout detection is probably going to be a waste of your time. I would just *assume you have connectivity* but then include error correction and tell the user if you couldn't get the data.

Oh, and if we were good enough programmers to prevent timeouts... We wouldn't be writing iPhone apps.

If you just make random pings all the time, you're going to A) slow the phone and B) not solve the problem. Timeouts happen for all sorts of reasons, and pinging probably won't prevent it.

On the other hand, if you *really* want to know about network state... Apple has this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

I should also note that [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) has this stuff built in... As far as I know, anyway - it requires it to compile on iPhone.

Comment: Yes, i have looked at the Reachability sample. It was very helpful.

Comment: And why do you think this is a waste of time? Are you suggesting this is impossible (to prevent timeouts)?

Comment: It depends what you mean by timeouts. If you mean the situations where a web server takes too long to respond and some point in the network kills the connection - it's probably worthless. If you mean the situations where a router just *forgets* about your computer and has to get a kick in the pants to start responding again, you may see a benefit. Fiddle with it, but do it in another thread. Users'll go nuts if their hardware freezes up once every few minutes.